# где скачать eel не через pypi

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно скачать eel для python, но не через pypi, что-бы можно было использовать без установки его через pypi.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/Eel/  ?

Answer (score 1):

C github можно скачать https://github.com/samuelhwilliams/Eel/releases

Установить можно через pip или скопировав папку eel в каталог проекта. Но не забудьте про зависимости

```
bottle==0.12.13
bottle-websocket==0.2.9
gevent==1.3.6
gevent-websocket==0.10.1
greenlet==0.4.15
pyparsing==2.4.7
whichcraft==0.4.1
```

Которые ставятся таким же образом.